# Relation between angle subtended by small circle inside a large one centered at a point on the circumference of the larger and radii

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

Consider a circle $C_1$ of radius $R$. Let $P$ be a point on the circumference of $C_1$, and $C_2$ be a circle of radius $x$ centered at $P$, as in the diagram. Then, can I derive a relation between the radii of the two circles, and the half angle $\theta$ subtended by the sector of $C_2$ that lies inside $C_1$?

[image]

I was doing a physics problem and if I'm able to find such a relation without introducing new variables I think I can solve it. I see that at $x=R, \theta = \frac\pi4; x=2R, \theta=0$ and as $x$ approaches $0, \theta$ approaches $\frac\pi2$. So does the linear relation $x=2R-\frac{4R\theta}{\pi}$ work for all values? Admittedly, the title is confusing, so suggested edits are appreciated.

Comment: I understand the definition of the dotted line used to define $\theta$. What is the precise definition of the second line used to define $\theta$. The solid one in your drawing.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net that would be the the line joining $P$ and the centre of the blue circle $C_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Please join $PQ$, centers of $C_2$ and $C_1$. As $ST$ is common chord of both circles, $PQ \perp ST$ and $PQ$ bisects the chord.

Now in $\triangle PQS, QP = QS = R$, so $\frac{PS}{2} = R \cos\theta$

But $PS$ is radius $r$ of circle $C_2$ so $r = 2R \cos\theta \implies \cos\theta = \displaystyle \frac{r}{2R}$

Answer (score 1):

I would say that

$$x=2 R \cos \theta.$$

For $x=R$ you have $\theta= \frac{\pi}{3}$ not $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: you're correct, except I think you made a typo, it would be $\frac\pi3$

Comment: @HridaiKhurana Indeed! Typo corrected.